# Alamofire global queue with pause between requests

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm working with an API which only permits a maximum of 5 requests per second. If this limit is exceeded the API returns a 429 server error.

My intuition says that to handle this, I should put all requests into some form of serial queue, and enforce a delay of 0.21s between requests, but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this. I'm also not sure if using a serial queue is a good idea, as then I'll lose the ability to have multiple requests running at the same time.

I am using adapter and retrier objects to handle refreshing my OAuth session token, so I guess this may be a good place to put my logic.

Has anyone done something like this before, or have any ideas?

Comment: I've now put in some very basic logic into my `RequestRetrier`, which basically retries after 0.25s if a 429 error is received. I'd rather be smarter about this though, and limit the requests on the client before they are even sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'd probably go a different direction, rather than trying to throttle all requests, I'd look at the response from each request and if it's a 429, I'd re-queue the request via an async closure with a 1 second time delay.

This means that as long as requests are coming in slowly they are executed immediately. But when you try the 6th request, it's shifted into the next second.

The only problem you're going to have to consider (regardless of solution) is what happens if requests keep coming in faster than the API will allow. ie. what happens if you get 6, or 7 or 100 requests per second, for every second? How are you going to deal with the extra requests that will never get executed.

At some point your code is going to have to start failing requests. Alternatively you need to push the server people to run up more servers or give you more bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's basically what I implemented soon after I posted the question (see my comment). To me it feels like there should be a better solution, ie. handle it on the client first rather than sending unnecessary requests. Good point re: too many requests as well, I don't think that's something I'm likely to come across but certainly worth considering how to handle that.